# prompt a user to the JRE installer

Tags: java, java-8, installation, bundle

What's the best way you use to prom a user who downloaded you Java application to install the JRE in case they do not have it?

I have been looking for a answer but i could not find resources to my question.
Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure your user has Java installed, the best choice would be to wrap your JAR file into a native executable using, e.g. [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

This software allows you to specify messages in case the user does not have a JRE installed and even gives you the opportunity to bundle a JRE which will be used for launching your application and much more.